# Jenkins MFA/2FA

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops

I need to setup multi factor authentication on users who login to Jenkins, using Google Authenticator. I looked on the internet and couldn't find any solution or jenkins plugin  to achieve this.

Does anyone have an idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could test:

- [OpenId Connect Authentication plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/oic-auth/)
  [image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkins-infra/plugins-wiki-docs/master/oic-auth/docs/images/image2019-1-21_1-26-36.png]
- [OpenID plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/openid/)
  [image: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jenkinsci/openid-plugin@master/docs/images/associate.png]

Both supports [Google OpenId endpoint](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect)

As discussed in [`jenkinsci/oic-auth-plugin` issue 25](https://github.com/jenkinsci/oic-auth-plugin/issues/25), that would bypass the MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication) though.

Comment: The thing is I am looking for a way to integrate two-factor authentication for the existing user login system using "Google Authenticator". As an example when a user tries to login into the dashboard using a username and password, then the user should also provide the 6 digits code from the "Google Authenticator" mobile app before entering to the dashboard.

Comment: @ThiranjayaMunasinghe I understand. I didn't see any plugin to that effect though.